# How to test privileged Firefox OS app before publishing in Marketplace?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mozilla, hybrid-mobile-app, firefox-os

I am trying to develop a privileged packaged firefox os app. And from MDN I came to know that privilaged apps will be verified and published by the marketplace. And there are certain API s like "mobilenetwork" which cannot be used with "web" type packaged apps. These type of API s cannot be tested in Firefox OS simulator too as mobilenetwork is not available in simulator.

During the course of development I may need to test it several times in my Firefox OS device. So how can I test a privilaged app in my device without publishing it in the marketplace?

I am new to firefox OS. So If I am wrong somewhere please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply **set privileged type in your manifest and install it to your phone via app-manager** (open the uri *about:app-manager* in firefox browser). See also [using the app-manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager). I am not familiar with the new web-ide but probably you can also use it to install privileged apps.

If someone wants to publish a privileged app in the market then Firefox may test the privileged app before approve it for public distribution. This only happens if you want to distribute your app in the market, not if you want to test it on your device.

Comment: But I have some issues with pushing the app to device as the device is not detected. So I always test my app by uploading it in my local apache server and use `navigator.mozApps.install(manifestURL);` to install the app.

Comment: Maybe Firefox does not allow to distribute privileged apps (market, server...) and only allows you to install them on your device via usb. Have you installed adb and adbHelper?

Comment: yes I did. I am using kali linux. And when I connect the device it is not getting detected. Maybe some driver issue. Worked around it a little but no hope. And my phone is Spice MIFX1 which uses firefox os 1.3. and is outdated now.

Comment: Remote debugging enabled?

Comment: Remote debugging is set to ADB and Devtools. Screen lock is disabled. I am using iceweasel 31.7.0

Comment: When I developed an app for Firefox OS some time ago I used an Alcatel One Touch Fire C (firefox os 1.3). I used Linux Mint, and I remember I enabled usb debugging on the phone, used the app manager,  installed adb helper; in addition I have android tools (it includes adb command) installed and added to path. I don't remember doing more than that. Wait to see if other user can help you or try with the new web IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Privileged apps may be distributed through the Firefox Marketplace only.
[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps)

Privileged apps are packaged apps that needs to be signed by a trusted party (Firefox Marketplace so far) and all its code is supposed to be contained in the app package. So you cannot load external scripts from a privileged app.

Hope it help.

Comment: I am not talking about external scripts. there are certain APIs provided by firefox which requires the app to be at least a privileged app (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Reference/Firefox_OS_device_APIs) and I cannot install a privileged app in my device as it is not signed by marketplace (Security error). But I want to test these APIs before I submit to market place. So how can I test?

Comment: For an app to use a specific API, it has to request access to that API in its manifest. If you just try your application locally you can disable the CSP restrictions by setting this preference in your device:

`pref("security.apps.privileged.CSP.default", "default-src *; script-src *; object-src 'none'; style-src *");`

The [CSP Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#csp) CMIIW

Comment: I am new to firefox OS. You mean adding the following lines to manifest file of app? 
`"type": "privileged",
  "csp" : "default-src *; script-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"`

Comment: Yes, please read the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/CSP